# Spring: Role-based redirecting after login

Tags: java, spring, security

I have three user roles {ADMIN, MANAGER, EMPLOYEE}. It already works that e.g. an Admin can access to /admin/** and so on. But what I really want to do is, when the user who just logged in with role ADMIN got redirected to e.g. welcome2.xhtml and all the other users who are not role ADMIN got redirected to e.g. welcome.xhtml.

Below the code I already have.

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                //Permit access to the H2 console
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                //Permit access for all to error pages
                .antMatchers("/error/**")
                .permitAll()
                // Only access with admin role
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                //Permit access only for some roles
                .antMatchers("/secured/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE")
                //If user doesn't have permission, forward him to login page
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/secured/welcome.xhtml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a custom authentication success handler which will check for the role and will redirect to appropriate pages. Try something like this one:

```
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException {

        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException {

        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            logger.debug(
              "Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to "
              + targetUrl);
            return;
        }

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {        
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        boolean isManager = false;
        boolean isEmployee = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_MANAGER")) {
                isManager = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_EMPLOYEEE")) {
                isEmployee = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isAdmin) {
            return "/welcome2.xhtml";
        } else if (isManager) {
            return "/welcome.xhtml";
        } else if (isEmployee) {
            return "/welcome.xhtml";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }

    protected void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return;
        }
        session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }
    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

And add this in your configuration

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                //Permit access to the H2 console
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                //Permit access for all to error pages
                .antMatchers("/error/**")
                .permitAll()
                // Only access with admin role
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                //Permit access only for some roles
                .antMatchers("/secured/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "MANAGER", "EMPLOYEE")
                //If user doesn't have permission, forward him to login page
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/secured/welcome.xhtml").successHandler(successHandler()) ;

@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    return new MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}
```

Comment: thank you - it works. can you explain how `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();` knows that the authorities are ROLES?